# Linking two interfaces on same subnet using dnsmasq

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm trying to configure my RPi to give me access to devices conencted either of eth0 or wlan1.

Desired function is this:

- User connects to RPi AP via wlan1 and is given an IP
- Separate device connects to RPi via eth0 and is given an IP
- User can access configuration interface of eth0 connected device via local IP address

So far I have managed to get my eth0 and wlan1 adapters configured to give IPs on two different subnets with the below dnsmasq and dhcpcd configurations;

```
# dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=wlan1,192.168.4.2,192.168.4.99,24h

interface=eth0
dhcp-range=eth0,192.168.5.1,192.168.5.99,24h

listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.5.1,192.168.4.1
```

```
# dhcpcd.conf
#wlan1 IP configuration
interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant

#eth0 configuration
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.5.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

However, I cannot access the eth0 connected device when I am connected via wifi, presumably because it is on a different subnet.
I have attempted to configure dnsmasq to have eth0 and wlan1 on the same subnet, but seems eth0 is not assigned an IP when I try this:

```
# dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=wlan1,192.168.4.2,192.168.4.100,24h

interface=eth0
dhcp-range=eth0,192.168.4.102,192.168.4.200,24h

listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1,192.168.4.1,192.168.4.101
```

```
# dhcpcd.conf
#wlan1 IP configuration
interface wlan1
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
nohook wpa_supplicant

#eth0 configuration
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.4.101/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

How do I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Would have thought its a routing issue rather than DHCP - if they are on different sub-nets something like net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 may be needed. Sorry LAN skills poor - not confident enough to put this as an answer :-)

Comment: It may be a routing issue, my LAN skills are also too poor to know!

Comment: *"I have attempted to configure dnsmasq to have eth0 and wlan1 on the same subnet"* -> That's not what you did.  There's nothing substantially different between the two configuration other than the IP ranges are different.  But they are not the same, hence, they are separate subnets. *[posterity: I'm wrong, did not look at the dhcpcd config correctly]*  You should edit in the output of `ip route`.

Comment: @goldilocks The first one has eth0 on 192.168.5.1 and wlan1 on 192.168.4.1, and I couldn't connect between devices on different interfaces. Perhaps I am wrong in why that is happening, though. Can you explain more about `ip route` ?

Comment: For some reason I hallucinated that you used the same range in the dhcpcd config so I guess in fact those are then on the same subnet.  Which I think cannot possibly work out, which is why I asked for the output from `ip route` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2).

Comment: ...I think the solution here is to bridge the interfaces, but I've never done exactly this.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/ - should have put this in my first post - sorry

Comment: Probably a better idea.  That doesn't show how to actually configure the forwarding but there should be lots of examples around.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe in "desired function" is [a network bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)), except perhaps it is unidirectional in some sense, which is essentially *a router*: Instead of an uplink, you have another subnet on the eth interface.  You could also consider it technically similar to an access point.

You should stay with the two subnets.  Trying to shove them together is *not* a simpler solution.

You could use [the linux virtual bridge](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge), for this, but I think it is more commonplace to use IP forwarding and NAT.  This is done with iptables; the standard series of commands would be something like:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan -j ACCEPT
```

The difference between this and a router or hotspot is that these would involve [network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation); you will see lots of examples of this using *ip masquerade*.

However, sans NAT this then requires that the connected parties have their own routing configured properly -- standard OS software will set up a route to the subnet of the interface they connect to a DHCP server through, but (unless you find a way to do this with dnsmasq, I don't know whether it is possible via the protocol<sup>1</sup>) **this tells the client system nothing about the other subnet.**

Quick fix on a linux client would be to add a route (or make the one to the pi bigger as per the footnote here):

```
ip route add 192.168.4.0/24 dev wlan0
```

That's presuming `wlan0` is what is connected to the Pi.  If you can't configure the clients, you will have to use NAT or the wider CIDR.

In case it is confusing about the "wider CIDR" in relation to the "two subnets", my point is that from the perspective of the Pi's routing, there should be two distinct subnets, one on each interface.  That's done with the `dhcpcd.conf` you have using `192.168.4.1/24` and `192.168.5.1/24`.  I presume you understand how CIDRs work (if not you need to), but these are both 256 addresses wide, with no overlap.  Hence if you look at `ip route` you should see one for each.

But if possible (this depends on whether DCHP allows for this, which it would be a bit silly if it didn't -- you'll have to figure out how to configure dnsmasq to do it), what you want clients on *both* interfaces to believe in is:

```
192.168.0.0/16
```

This CIDR is twice as wide in terms of bits (32 - 16 = 16 vs. 32 - 24 = 8), and 256 times wider in terms of addresses (so, 65536).  It includes both 192.168.4.0/24 and 192.168.5.0/24.

This way, the clients will configure their own routing to use the link to the for that entire wider range.  Eg., 192.168.4.10 will send packets to the Pi for 192.168.5.42, and because of the forwarding rules, those will passed straight through as is to the other interface.<sup>2</sup>

The potential problem with this is clients might not be able to correctly connect with others on their own subnet.  If that matters, some more complex iptables rules will be needed.

---

1. What would make it apply is if the CIDR used by the DHCP server were sufficient to include both subnets, eg. 192.168.0.0/16.
2. You don't have to use `/16`; 15 bits will cover up to 192.168.7.255 so you could use `/27`.

Comment: I think I follow the first bit, I'll give that a try. I'm not sure what you mean about wlan0 and the size of the route though.

Comment: I had to alter the `iptables` command replacing `-D` with `-A` because it was giving me an error about not matching an existing rule.

Comment: Yes whoops! I cut and pasted that from a script which was for disabling not enabling (you should be checking the `man` pages for these commands before you use them, people on the internet can make nastier mistakes than that ;).  Anyway I've also added a bit at the end explaining what I mean by "wider CIDR".

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think I mostly understand what you're saying, but I'm falling down at the actual implementation, which is obviously the key part here! You mention wlan0 a few times, which I assume is a typo since I have no current need to access subnets via that connection. When I set up the iptables rules, and the route with 192.168.0.0/16 on wlan1 I don't see any difference. I really don't feel much further on with this unfortunately :(

Comment: I used wlan0 for the example.  It doesn't really matter what the name of the interface is.  *"and the route with 192.168.0.0/16 on wlan1"* -> That's not what I said, unless you mean you are configuring that route manually on one of the connected systems (not the pi), or you found a way to do this via `dnsmasq`... I am thinking WRT to that you try using the exact same range for both interfaces in dnsmasq.conf (the /16 one).  But no where else, at least one the Pi.  For its own routing it has to see those as two distinct subnets.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to just create a stock AP using `hostapd` (lots of examples online) and try to tweak it to your circumstances.  What you want is sort of a bi-directional AP, where the uplink is just the subnet on the other interface.  If you don't actually need it bi-directional (all you've said is you want clients on the wifi to be able to access stuff on the eth), then it is even more like a straight AP.